How can I export a Figma animation as a gif with transparent background?
I have created a series of animations in Figma that I need to use in a website. I need to export them as animated GIFs with transparent background. I've tried some Figma plugins, but none of them offer background transparency.
Any thoughts?
I tried the following:

"Export to GIF Video" Figma plugin
Using After Effects to remove the backround.

